# How to remove "Ad by browser shop" Ad from browser

Tags: trojan

[image]

How can I remove this Ad? I get it in all pages. I try to clean it with Spybot Search and Destroy but not working.

Answer (score 3):

[AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) removes the application "Browser Shop" and other [potentially unwanted programs](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/PUP) that change search, homepage, and gather data for marketing purposes.

These applications usually come offered with other applications during their install process. Remember to choose a 'custom install' and uncheck offers provided by these programs.

Comment: I tried but is still the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: @senzacionale Is there a control panel area for it?